# Why am I getting an error in this php endif statement?

Tags: php

from the yt video im watching theres no error in his code while i am getting an error

```
<?php if(count($errors)>0); ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>    
                        <li><?php echo $error; ?> </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: There's a semicolon after the opening if statement.

Answer (score 0):

From *User Contributed Notes* of PHP doc for [if](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#112231), the correct syntax is:

```
<?php if (condition): ?>

// HTML code to run if condition is true

<?php else: ?>

// HTML code to run if condition is false

<?php endif ?>
```

You must change the semicolon after the opening if statement to a colon. The closing semicolons are optional.

So your code should look like this:

```
<?php if(count($errors)>0): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>    
            <li><?php echo $error; ?> </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

...